# What additional data value would keep perfectly constant the variance of the now larger dataset

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation

Playing with the algebra this is easy to figure out for the mean, but I can't solve it for the variance.     Please   notice it's not about the properties of the variance with regard to systematic shifts by addition or multiplication.
Help and thoughts are welcome.

Comment: I think you mean adding a new observation to a sample so that if you had $50$ subjects with standard deviation $s$, upon observing a $51$st subject, calculating the value of that subject such that all $51$ still have a standard deviation of $s$.

Comment: indeed Dave, I am not being able to edit my own question though.

Answer (score 2):

You can find relevant updating formulae for the sample mean and variance in [O'Neill (2014)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2014.966589).  These formulae let you update the sample mean and variance when you combine two subsamples of any size.  If you add a single data point to an existing sample of size $n$, the updated recursive formula for the sample variance  (Result 1, p. 283) is:

$$s_{n+1}^2 = \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot s_n^2 + \frac{1}{n+1} \cdot (\bar{x}_n - x_{n+1})^2.$$

Taking $s_{n+1}^2 = s_n^2$ to leave the sample variance unchanged, and solving for $x_{n+1}$, gives the requirement:

$$x_{n+1} = \bar{x}_n \pm \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} \cdot s_n.$$

Here is a numerical example in `R`:

```
#Create mock dataset
set.seed(1);
n   <- 20;
XX  <- rnorm(n);

#Create new data point
x   <- mean(XX) + sqrt((n+1)/n)*sd(XX);

#Show variance of datasets
var(XX);
[1] 0.8340324

var(c(XX, x));
[1] 0.8340324

identical(var(XX), var(c(XX, x)))
TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Ben , Could you provide a minimal numerical example? my excel version gets close to the solution, but for the solution clearly still  happens that : $$s_{n+1}!=s_{n}$$